# hadoop mapReduce job never finished

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I have hadoop cluster and I'm trying to run wordcount job from my java code that runs on another machine using REST API. Here how I run the job

```
  Configuration conf = new Configuration();

  conf.set("yarn.resourcemanager.address", resourceManagerAddress); 
  conf.set("mapreduce.framework.name", "yarn");
  conf.set("fs.default.name", fsDefaultName);

 Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Rest WC job2");
job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(inputPath));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outputPath));
job.submit();
```

Job get submitted to the cluster and I can see it in hadoop UI console however when looking to slave log I can see following:

```
2017-11-01 09:03:21,669 INFO SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Auth successful for appattempt_1509459563039_0017_000001 (auth:SIMPLE)
2017-11-01 09:03:21,676 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Start request for container_1509459563039_0017_01_000001 by user root
2017-11-01 09:03:21,677 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Creating a new application reference for app application_1509459563039_0017
2017-11-01 09:03:21,677 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=root IP=10.56.0.93   OPERATION=Start Container Request       TARGET=ContainerManageImpl      RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1509459563039_0017    CONTAINERID=container_1509459563039_0017_01_000001
2017-11-01 09:03:21,677 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationImpl: Application application_1509459563039_0017 transitioned from NEW to INITING
2017-11-01 09:03:21,677 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationImpl: Adding container_1509459563039_0017_01_000001 to application application_1509459563039_0017
2017-11-01 09:03:21,678 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationImpl: Application application_1509459563039_0017 transitioned from INITING to RUNNING
2017-11-01 09:03:21,678 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1509459563039_0017_01_000001 transitioned from NEW to LOCALIZING
2017-11-01 09:03:21,678 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event CONTAINER_INIT for appId application_1509459563039_0017
2017-11-01 09:03:21,678 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalizedResource: Resource hdfs://<master_ip_address>:9000/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1509459563039_0017/job.jar transitioned from INIT to DOWNLOADING
2017-11-01 09:03:21,678 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalizedResource: Resource hdfs://<master_ip_address>:9000/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1509459563039_0017/job.splitmetainfo transitioned from INIT to DOWNLOADING
2017-11-01 09:03:21,678 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalizedResource: Resource hdfs://<master_ip_address>:9000/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1509459563039_0017/job.split transitioned from INIT to DOWNLOADING
2017-11-01 09:03:21,678 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalizedResource: Resource hdfs://<master_ip_address>:9000/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1509459563039_0017/job.xml transitioned from INIT to DOWNLOADING
2017-11-01 09:03:21,678 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Created localizer for container_1509459563039_0017_01_000001
2017-11-01 09:03:21,680 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Writing credentials to the nmPrivate file /tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/nmPrivate/container_1509459563039_0017_01_000001.tokens. Credentials list: 
2017-11-01 09:03:21,689 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Initializing user root
2017-11-01 09:03:21,690 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Copying from /tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/nmPrivate/container_1509459563039_0017_01_000001.tokens to /tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1509459563039_0017/container_1509459563039_0017_01_000001.tokens
2017-11-01 09:03:21,690 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Localizer CWD set to /tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1509459563039_0017 = file:/tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1509459563039_0017
2017-11-01 09:03:22,055 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalizedResource: Resource hdfs://<master_ip_address>:9000/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1509459563039_0017/job.jar(->/tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1509459563039_0017/filecache/10/job.jar) transitioned from DOWNLOADING to LOCALIZED
2017-11-01 09:03:22,073 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalizedResource: Resource hdfs://<master_ip_address>:9000/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1509459563039_0017/job.splitmetainfo(->/tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1509459563039_0017/filecache/11/job.splitmetainfo) transitioned from DOWNLOADING to LOCALIZED
2017-11-01 09:03:22,092 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalizedResource: Resource hdfs://<master_ip_address>:9000/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1509459563039_0017/job.split(->/tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1509459563039_0017/filecache/12/job.split) transitioned from DOWNLOADING to LOCALIZED
2017-11-01 09:03:22,111 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalizedResource: Resource hdfs://<master_ip_address>:9000/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1509459563039_0017/job.xml(->/tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1509459563039_0017/filecache/13/job.xml) transitioned from DOWNLOADING to LOCALIZED
2017-11-01 09:03:22,111 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1509459563039_0017_01_000001 transitioned from LOCALIZING to LOCALIZED
2017-11-01 09:03:22,131 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1509459563039_0017_01_000001 transitioned from LOCALIZED to RUNNING
2017-11-01 09:03:22,135 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: launchContainer: [bash, /tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1509459563039_0017/container_1509459563039_0017_01_000001/default_container_executor.sh]
2017-11-01 09:03:23,755 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Starting resource-monitoring for container_1509459563039_0017_01_000001
2017-11-01 09:03:23,768 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 4957 for container-id container_1509459563039_0017_01_000001: 135.8 MB of 2 GB physical memory used; 1.6 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used
2017-11-01 09:03:26,770 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 4957 for container-id container_1509459563039_0017_01_000001: 232.3 MB of 2 GB physical memory used; 1.6 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used
2017-11-01 09:03:29,772 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 4957 for container-id container_1509459563039_0017_01_000001: 296.7 MB of 2 GB physical memory used; 1.7 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used
2017-11-01 09:03:32,773 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 4957 for container-id container_1509459563039_0017_01_000001: 296.7 MB of 2 GB physical memory used; 1.7 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used
2017-11-01 09:03:35,775 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 4957 for container-id container_1509459563039_0017_01_000001: 296.7 MB of 2 GB physical memory used; 1.7 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used
2017-11-01 09:03:38,777 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 4957 for container-id container_1509459563039_0017_01_000001: 296.7 MB of 2 GB physical memory used; 1.7 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used
2017-11-01 09:03:41,778 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 4957 for container-id container_1509459563039_0017_01_000001: 296.7 MB of 2 GB physical memory used; 1.7 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used
2017-11-01 09:03:44,780 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 4957 for container-id container_1509459563039_0017_01_000001: 296.7 MB of 2 GB physical memory used; 1.7 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used
2017-11-01 09:03:47,781 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 4957 for container-id container_1509459563039_0017_01_000001: 296.7 MB of 2 GB physical memory used; 1.7 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used
2017-11-01 09:03:50,784 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 4957 for container-id container_1509459563039_0017_01_000001: 296.7 MB of 2 GB physical memory used; 1.7 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used
```

Note last few lines. The numbers are keep growing and job never completes

In hadoop ui I can see

```
YarnApplicationState:   ACCEPTED: waiting for AM container to be allocated, launched and register with RM.
```

and system stucks in this state.

I can run wordcount job from hadoop master by running hadoop jar .... command and it finished properly so cluster is configured and working.

What can be the problem?

Thanks

UPD. Last lines from yarn--resourcemanager on master node

```
2017-11-01 11:49:04,630 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl: appattempt_1509459563039_0020_000001 State change from ALLOCATED to LAUNCHED
2017-11-01 11:49:05,620 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl: container_1509459563039_0020_01_000001 Container Transitioned from ACQUIRED to RUNNING
```

Answer (score 0):

Job hasnt even started executing.  There are no free conatiners available in your YARN hence job cannot start.

Its not a error but normal YARN application state transition.

Comment: I can run same job from master node using hadoop jar command so containers are available

Comment: So all you are saying is from a datanode or a client node the jar is not getting executed ? please clarify

Comment: I have master node and slave node. In addition I have another node in the same network. I can run hadoop jar from this node without any issue, however when using Java client from same node, job is submitted bun never ends.